# Copy parts of row if match across workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm having two files to work with. One is the file to be updated, the other one contains new data.

Both files contain material numbers and information about this material (quantities etc), so i want all of the fresh values (which are part of the same row) to be copied into the right place of the row in the other file.

I managed to get everything working except a VLOOKUP (which should be needed..).

Anyone? :)

```
'################################################################################################
'################################################################################################
'######### fnopen():    Opens a FileDialog, allowing the user to choose the GLA File.   #########
'#########              Returns directory/filename of selected as String                #########
'################################################################################################
'################################################################################################

Function fnopen() As String

    Dim strFileToOpen As String

    strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (Title:="Please choose GLA501 to open")
        '# Change name of FileDialog (is being displayed)
    Workbooks.Open filename:=strFileToOpen
    '# Open Workbook
    fnopen = strFileToOpen
    MsgBox fnopen & "     1"
    MsgBox strFileToOpen & "     2"

End Function

'################################################################################################
'################################################################################################

'################################################################################################
'######### MakeRow(): Creates String of Cell out of row and String                      #########
'################################################################################################

Function MakeRow(rowno As Integer, col As String) As String

    MakeRow = col & CStr(rowno)

End Function

'################################################################################################
'######### getmat():    Requires row no. and returns material no.                       #########
'################################################################################################

Function getmat(rowno As Integer, col As String) As String

    getmat = Range(MakeRow(rowno, col)).Value

End Function

'################################################################################################
'################################################################################################

Function fcat(gla_path As String, gla_name As String, lastrow As Integer) As Integer

    Dim srchRange As Range, found_in_location As Range, lookFor As Range
    Dim rowno As Integer, counter As Integer
    Dim col As String

    rowno = 16
    col = "F"

    counter = 0

    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim book2 As Workbook

    Set book1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set book2 = Workbooks(gla_name)

    Set lookFor = book2.Sheets(1).Cells(rowno, 6)   ' value to find
    Set srchRange = book1.Sheets(2).Range(MakeRow(rowno, col), MakeRow(lastrow, col))    'source

    Set found_in_location = srchRange.Columns(1).Find(What:=lookFor, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not found_in_location Is Nothing Then
      found_in_location.Offset(0, 85).Value = lookFor.Offset(0, 79)
    Else
      counter = counter + 1
    End If

    fcat = counter

End Function

'################################################################################################
'################################################################################################

Sub annualazy()

    Dim gla_path As String, gla_name As String, col As String, rowno As Integer, counter As Integer, lastrow As Integer

    MsgBox ("This VBA updates 'DC_Annual_Planning' by copying values from '4510_GLA501_DC'. Make sure to select the correct files!")
    gla_path = fnopen()
    gla_name = Right(gla_path, Len(gla_path) - InStrRev(gla_path, "\"))

    rowno = 16
    col = "F"

    lastrow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
    MsgBox lastrow

    MsgBox gla_name
    MsgBox getmat(rowno, col)
    MsgBox fcat(gla_path, gla_name, lastrow)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the value you search for simply isn't found, and that is what creates your problem?

Anyway, when working in VBA, I prefer using [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx) over `VLOOKUP`. Without reviewing the rest of your code, and assuming the line you have problems with is `lookFor.Offset(0, 79).Value = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchRange, 2, False)`, you can replace it with something like:

```
Dim found_in_location As Range
Set found_in_location = srchRange.Columns(1).Find(What:=lookFor, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
If Not found_in_location Is Nothing Then
  lookFor.Offset(0, 79).Value = found_in_location.Offset(0, 2)
Else
  ' What will you do if the value is not found?
End If
```

While it takes up a bit more space than the `VLOOKUP`-line, it is both easier to read and to debug.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, just one question: am i right, that this will take the value of the cell which is 2 cells away from found_in_location and pastes it into the cell 79 cells to the right from lookfor, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct (those are the offsets in the first part of the if statement). If you want to try it out, you can always make a copy of your project to try it out in, potentially with some `MsgBox`es or `Debug.Print`-statements intespersed in the code, to help you get an overview of what happens at different points in it. Oh, and if you find this answer satisfactory, I would appreciate it if you mark it as accepted by checking the mark next to the top of it (under the arrows) @Lukas

Comment: Just tested it... and it runs! Thank you very much :)

Comment: sorry revoke this, but this does NOT find the number its searching for (counter says 1, its counting not-founds). but since everything else semms to be working like a charm i guess i messed up this one line of code somehow. do you have a good reference for me, so i can teach myself this search stuff? [updated my code in #1)